# Python. Подскажите пожалуйста почему не работает конструкция if else когда я ее ужимаю в одну сторку

Tags: python, if

Без сокращения работает.

```
s = input()
k, l, m = -1, len(s)//2, 0
for i in range(l):
    if s[i] == s[k]:
        k-=1
    else:
        m=1
print("it is") if m==0 else print("its not")
```

С сокращением не работает.

```
s = input()
k, l, m = -1, len(s)//2, 0
for i in range(l):
    k-=1 if s[i]==s[k] else m=1
print("it is") if m==0 else print("it's not")
```

Это программа определяющая вводится полиндром или нет. Зачем я ужимаю в 1 строку это дело 10ое, я просто хочу научиться это делать и разобраться почему не работает.

Comment: Питон видит `k-=1 if s[i]==s[k] else m=1` как `k -= (1 если ... иначе m = 1)`, вот и ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тернарный оператор работает для expressions, а не для statements.

Поэтому можно написать так:

```
k -= 1 if s[i]==s[k] else -1
```

Но нельзя так:

```
k-=1 if s[i]==s[k] else m=1
```

Для принта всё в порядке.

Answer (score 0):

1 вариант.

```
    s = input()
    k, l, m = -1, len(s)//2, 0
    for i in range(l):
        if s[i] == s[k]:
            k-=1
        else:
            m=1
    print("it is") if m==0 else print("its not")
```

2 вариант.

```
    s = input()
    k, l, m = -1, len(s)//2, 0
    for i in range(l):
        k-=1 if s[i]==s[k] else m=1
    print("it is") if m==0 else print("it's not")
```

Comment: `k-=1 if s[i]==s[k] else m=1` работать не будет - покажет синтаксическую ошибку.

Comment: Если это дополнение к вопросу, то вставляйте его в сам вопрос с помощью "править"